# Filtering out invalid user inputs

Tags: c++, stl, validation

I'm trying to filter out invalid user inputs in a small C++ program using the following chunk of code:

```
    int selection = -1;
    while (!(selection >= 1 && selection <=4))
    {   
        cin >> selection;

        if (!(selection >= 1 && selection <=4))
        {
            cout << "invalid selection!" << endl;
            cout << "selection: ";
        }
    }
```

It seems to work fine when I enter any numerical value that is either inside or outside the range i want to filter. However strange things happen when I enter invalid values such as values larger than the maximum storable int or characters. The code loops through and skipping the "cin" command.

How do I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to detect unconvertible input using `fail()` and then ignore the rest of the bad data and reset `cin` error flags using `clear()` before reading in a new input attempt.

```
int selection = -1;
while (!(selection >= 1 && selection <=4))
{   
    cin >> selection;

    if (cin.fail() || !(selection >= 1 && selection <=4))
    {
        cout << "invalid selection!" << endl;
        cout << "selection: ";

        cin.clear();

        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are two suggestions for fixing your issue:

1. Add Error Handling to `cin`
2. Read as String And Parse

The common solution is Read As String And Parse, but I'm presenting both for you to choose.

### Add Error Handling to `cin`

When the stream extraction function receives a character that is not suited for numerics, it sets a `fail` bit.  You need to check the state of the stream (`cin`) for failure.  If you want to continue, you need to clear the error state.

The state can be checked by using the `fail` method:  `cin.fail()`.  To clear the state use:  `cin.clear()`.

See [C++ Online Reference -- istream](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/io/start)

### Read As String And Parse

An alternative is read the input as a string, then parse the string for your data.  The `string` container has some useful methods for parsing.

Use `getline` to read in a `string` variable from `cin`.

Again, you will have to write code to check for errors and process them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check condition of `cin`, and if it is any error states, you should clear the error flag and `ignore()`:

```
int main()
{
    int selection = -1;
    while (!(selection >= 1 && selection <=4))
    {
        if (cin >> selection)
        {
            if (!(selection >= 1 && selection <=4))
            {
                cout << "invalid selection!" << endl;
                cout << "selection: ";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
        }
    }

    cout << selection << " selected\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Another way is to read everything as `string` and let the `stringstream` do error check:

```
int main()
{
    int selection = -1;
    while (!(selection >= 1 && selection <=4))
    {
        string line;
        getline(cin, line);

        stringstream sstr(line);
        if (sstr >> selection)
        {
            if (!(selection >= 1 && selection <=4))
            {
                cout << "invalid selection!" << endl;
                cout << "selection: ";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "invalid input!" << endl;
            cout << "selection: ";
        }
    }

    cout << selection << " selected\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** You may need to put a `cin.ignore();` right after `getline()` call - depending on if you are reading all unformatted input or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should read `cin` into a std::string and start your validation from there. Check that the value is numeric, for starters.

Answer (score -1):

When you enter letters for example it puts `cin` into a bad state and leaves those characters. You need to `ignore` them (`cin.ignore(1024, '\n')`) so it knows to move on to the next line of input.

Comment: How exactly would i use this ignore? What does cin.ignore(1024) mean? Specifically the 1024 part.

Comment: This tells to ignore the next 1024 characters, which is wrong, because the next 1024 characters will be ignored.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to use cin.ignore(1024, '\n') which tells to ignore all characters until a newline character is found or 1024 characters has been ignored

Comment: Ugh, indeed, only ignore up to a newline.